# how to view database tables in xampp

Tags: database, xampp

I want to view my database tables in xampp using "phpmyadmin panel".But iam getting this error

```
Access forbidden!
```

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
09/06/13 16:53:15
Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i PHP/5.2.9

WHAT TO DO?

Comment: You want to open phpmyadmin or what?

Comment: @ polymorphin yes i want to access phpmyadmin,but iam getting the above error

Comment: Which path did you tried to open phpmyadmin?